# Login to ofbiz fails with "Received null security object from HttpServletRequest

Tags: ofbiz

I've freshly installed Ofbiz. Below are the versions.

Java: Temurin-11.0.22+7
Ofbiz: 18.12.11

Started ofbiz services, but there are errors during login. No login panel appears, I could see the following errors in the logs.

2024-01-29 09:14:02,552 |jsse-nio-8443-exec-5 |LoginWorker                   |W| Received a null Security object from HttpServletRequest
2024-01-29 09:14:02,552 |jsse-nio-8443-exec-5 |ControlFilter                 |I| [Filtered request]: /catalog/control/main --> /control/main

Answer (score 0):

An answer tentative has been done at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-12882 please check there, TIA